# What's the difference between %r and repr()?

Tags: python

I was wondering if anyone can explain me what's the difference between these two representations `%r` and `repr()`

```
>>> repr(tuple()) 
'()'
```

But when using

```
>>> '%r' % tuple()
{TypeError}not enough arguments for format string
```

Comment: When you use the `%` based string formatting, it takes a *sequence* of arguments. You passed it an empty tuple, which is being interpreted as the sequence of arguments. Since it is empty, and your format specification specifies a single argument, it throws an error. You probably shouldn't be using `%` based string formatting anyway, and instead, use `.format` or f-strings.

Comment: `repr()` is a function (which could be compared to `print()`). `%r` is a formatting option.

Comment: You'd need a one-tuple of an empty tuple: `'%r' % (tuple(),)`.

Answer (score 0):

There should be theoretically no difference between the two. However, the `%` syntax takes a tuple, and iterates through its contents. Your second example provides an empty tuple, which cannot be iterated over, as there are no elements! The `repr` function has no such stipulation, as it simply takes an object in, rather than a tuple to iterate over. You will see identical results if you run

```
'%r' % (tuple(),)
```